# Filter HTML Content with JQuery but exclude certain elements

Tags: jquery, html, filter

I have a list of posts and I'd like to remove all text/HTML content except the content set "strong".

**Original**

```
<li id="post">
    <p>
        <strong>Reality</strong>
    </p>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    </p>
</li>
<li id="post">
    <p>
        <strong>Buzz</strong><br>
        <br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    </p>
</li>
<li id="post">
    <p>
        <strong>Innovation</strong><br>
        <br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    </p>
</li>
```

**Desired Result**

```
<li id="post">
        Reality
</li>
<li id="post">
        Buzz
</li>
<li id="post">
        Innovation
</li>
```

How can I do this using JQuery?

Comment: FYI, id's should be unique so you should probably change id="post" to class="post".

Comment: Your acceptance-rate-is-great! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution will be to make a selector that selects all strong $("strong") then remove all li's and then .each item in $("strong"), append it inside a new li.

---

Update:

You can try this: http://jsfiddle.net/6awfe/

```
$("li#post").each( function()
    {
        $(this).html("[strong start tag]" + $("strong", this).html()+"[strong end tag]");
    } )
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below works as intended. **Replace `id="post"` by `class="post"`!!**

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GfsCB/**

```
$("li.post").each(function(){
    var filtered = $("<li>").append($("strong", this).text())
    $(this).replaceWith(filtered);
});
```

1. Loop through each `<li>` item.
2. Create a new `<li>` element, and append the text content of all `<strong>` elements
3. Replace the currently selected `<li>` element by the just-created `<li>` element (`filtered`).

Answer (score 0):

My solution will be to make a selector that selects all strong $("strong") then remove all li's and then .each item in $("strong"), append it inside a new li.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you on your way:

```
var htmlText = "";
$('.post').find('strong').each(function() {
    htmlText += "<li class=\"post\">" + $(this).text() + "</li>";
});

alert(htmlText);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.post').each(function(){
    $(this).html($('strong', this).text());
});
```

Change id="post" to class="post" as others also state.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're going to change `id='post'` to `class='post'` (`id`s should be unique):

```
$("li.post").each(function() {
   $(this).text($(this).find("strong").text());
});
```

This retains all attributes associated to the list item and only replaces the content.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BRnZh/